# Added ContentDocumentLink to Library but Library Members Can't See Record

Tags: contentversion, contentdocument, content, contentdocumentlink

So I have a ContentVersion that gets added to a record, then I create a ContentDocumentLink record connecting that File to the Library. That Library includes community users. How come they can't see the files, do I have to create another record of some sort?
I check the library and the new file is there.

Comment: I'm not sure the answer to this, but did you check the saretype when creating the ContentDocumentLink record? I know visibility doesn't affect libraries, so that is the only thing I can think that is affecting it.

Comment: I have it as 'I' because it's in a library

Comment: Hmm, "I" sounds like the correct sharing type for Libraries. Have you tested with other files (not posted to records first, but uploaded directly to that library) to see if the community user can see it? Just want to rule out an issue with the libreary visibility itself.

Comment: Yeah if I add a file to library and then add that file to the record through the UI, it works. I'm thinking maybe it's a different record that manages the permission between the library and the community or something weird

Comment: Hmm, interesting. "For organizations with Communities enabled, a document can only be shared with users and groups that are a part of the community the file was created in." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm

Comment: I had an issue that was different in our org, but we solved with a solution that might work for you as well. I can work it up as an answer if you would like this alternative

Comment: I'm all ears...

Comment: Are you ok with having the files have public urls that can be tied to another object? If so, I can post the answer. If that is a security vulnerability you're not comfortable with, then my solution won't work.